# Iframes loading with progress bar using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, progress-bar

in my job (intranet)- I have an aspx page which has many Iframes ( all ours).

each iframe is being set(js/jquery) by btnX ( there are many buttons in the aspx page... some set src to iframes - some not).

[image]

*notice : the progrssBAr is on the main page...*

goal : progressBar while iframe is loading...

code :
( at first the `myPageWrapper` is `display:none`)

```
$('#myPageWrapper').on ('load','iframe',function () { $("#myProgressBar").hide();});
```

2 problems  :

- i can listen to the iframes load finish event. but what about `showing` the ProgfressBar ?
  i dont want to edit all btn's event "onclick" - is there any centralized solution to this [using jquery]?

i need something that does :

*"when btn sets the `src` to an iframe - show `myProgressBar`"*

- simultaneous events can occur : iframe **A** is being loading for 2 min ( example)  - so it shows the progress bar , *meanwhile* i pressed other button which sets `src` to iframe **B**  - which is loading very fast... once its loaded - it hides the ProgressBar ( look at my code) - **but** it shouldnt...**A** didnt finish yet....

Comment: Maybe a stupid question, but do you need iframes? you can also use ajax to load the divs.

Comment: this is what you need: http://easyxdm.net/wp/ - Cross-Domain Messaging made easy

Comment: @JPHellemons on my intranet job....they created pages and set the src .... sometimes it better to use iframe - you dont have everything in 1 page... you can test indevidual page etc... i know its bad for SEO. but thats not the question

Comment: Ok, was just wondering if iframe was a requirement.

Comment: @aSeptik there isnt cross domains here....all ours.

Comment: last question: do the progress bar need to listen all the iframes or one by one?

Comment: @aSeptik all the iframes ....`on ('load','iframe'` the iframe word here represents the element tag....didnt put class/ID... but is it that matter ? :)

Comment: @aSeptik I guess the problem is to listen to SRC change ( not when LOAD !!! - its too late.... i need when it first change the SRC - so i can show the Progress Bar)....

Comment: the way to go is the `postMessage` function, give some min i'm writing a full working demo for you...

Comment: @aSeptik wow... really appriciate... p.s. the problem with multi operations can be solved via FLag... its minor... the core is what we are talking about...:)

Comment: see the example http://ask.altervista.org/demo/iframes-loading-with-progress-bar-using-jquery/ let me know if i should implement the progress animation too...

Comment: @Royi Namir: how do you solved in the end?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## CODE UPDATED

- **NOTE**:  <del>since i received 3 up-votes i assume that this code is helping someone else other then the original OP; so i decided to update the code to reflect what it was meant to be at the beginning, since so far the OP and i have discovered that his problem was somewhere else in his code.</del>

> **demo:**  http://so.lucafilosofi.com/iframes-loading-with-progress-bar-using-jquery/

head of main page

```
        var iframes = [], progress = 0;
        $(function() {
            $pGressIndex = $('#progress-bar-indicator');
            $('#navigation a').click(function() {

                var iframe_id = this.hash.split('#')[1];

                if (iframes.indexOf(iframe_id) === -1) {

                    $('#log').prepend('<p><strong>' + iframe_id + '</strong> is loading!</p>');

                    iframes.push(iframe_id);

                    if (parseInt($pGressIndex.width()) == 960) {
                        $pGressIndex.removeAttr('style');
                    }

                    var fW = (iframes.length > 1) ? (660 - (20 * iframes.length ) ) : 660;

                    $pGressIndex.animate({
                        width : fW
                    }, 5000);

                    var iframe_page = iframe_id + '.html';

                    if ($(this.hash).length != 0) {
                        $(this.hash).remove();
                    }

                    $('<iframe>').attr({
                        id : iframe_id,
                        src : iframe_page,
                        frameBorder : 0,
                        width : 960
                    }).appendTo('#iframes-wrapper');
                }
                return false;
            });
        });
```

bottom of main page:

```
            window.addEventListener("message", function(e) {
                console.log(iframes);
                var index = iframes.indexOf(e.data);
                iframes.splice(index, 1);
                if (iframes.length == 0) {
                    $pGressIndex.stop(true).animate({
                        width : 960
                    }, 100);
                }
                $('#' + e.data).show();
            }, false);
```

bottom of each iframe page:

```
           top.postMessage('frame-name-or-what-you-want', window.location.href);
```

Comment: I dont have words to appreciate your effort and help.  thank you :)

Comment: @Royi Namir: i'm going to add some little fix and comment source..! you are welcome and i'm happy that it helped...

Comment: why didnt you listen to the load event for each iframe?

Comment: i have currently ( for example) 100 iframe on my page. each is being set a SRC by different button. where is the line which tells me : "someone has set a SRC attr to an iframe " ?  do i need to listen to all buttons in page ? **i just need those events who set SRC **

Comment: you have to listen all buttons, yes, you basically list the click event, so when someone click a button you know that an iframe is going to be created....

Comment: i don't use load here, cause in my example load does not respect the setTimeout() i used in the iframe page

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10753/discussion-between-aseptik-and-royi-namir)

Comment: @Royi Namir: the only thing that could expect different behaviour is postMessage call, but seams to be supported enough. (but this is subjective ) read: http://caniuse.com/#feat=x-doc-messaging.