# Jquery Load Iframe using progress bar

Tags: jquery

I want to load an `iframe` and i have jquery included in my file. my `iframe` takes a few seconds to load. i want to display a progress bar while my `iframe` is loading and when `iframe` loaded then that progress bar hide

I need help on this.
I tried a simple jquery code.

I really have no idea how to write code for this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: posslible duplicate, check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10397486/iframes-loading-with-progress-bar-using-jquery

Comment: but there is no answer of my question? Where they use the progress bar image