# How to know de % download of a web page

Tags: javascript, web

I'm making a mini-web project (can see it [here](http://www.whiteplay.fr)).
Is it possible to know the download percentage of the current page ? (JavaScript)
If so how ? This is for loading animation (the blue loader).
[image]

Comment: Dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29113422/how-to-track-the-download-percentage-using-jquery-javascript.

Comment: Related: [How does Feed.ly determine iFrame load progress?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28353988/3187556)

Comment: Thanks, but theses answers are talking about a file download and an iframe loader. I don't will put my website in an iframe just to have a loader :/ Am i right ? And if i do it, it's just a fake loader true ?