# Display progress bar when iframe is loading in ie

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, iframe

Ive got a web application with an iframe in the application. In internet explorer 10 when the user is navigating the content in my iframe it's not always obvious that something is happening when the iframe content is loading. i.e. there is no loading progress bar etc...

Is there a good way to change the way the iframe displays in ie so that I gett a loading progress bar? If not is there an event in jquery that can pick up when an iframe is loading (not just the initial load but also all subsequent loads).

thanks

Comment: You mean like the one in this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10397486/iframes-loading-with-progress-bar-using-jquery)?

Comment: Hi. I did see that link but I'm not sure if that is only for inital load. Is it for everytime that the iframe is loading?